# how to use a string value as a key, in fetching a json array in angular forEach

Tags: angularjs

```
var variable="static";
    $scope.arrCategory=[{
        'static': [{'theme1': [{'name':'vari-1',
                                'picture':'./images/static/theme-1/vari-1/1.jpg',
                                'price':'10000'}]
                   },
                   {'theme2':  {'name':'vari-1',
                                'picture':'./images/static/theme-2/vari-1/1.jpg',
                                'price':'10000'
                   }
                  ]
        }];

    angular.forEach($scope.arrCategory[0].variable,function(k,d){
        //alert(k);
        angular.forEach(k,function(kk, dd){
            alert(dd);
        });
    });
```

In this case I have to pass a "static" string as a key name as you can see in the above.

`var variable="static";` is what i have in my hand. Actually, I have to put it in the foreach.i try to convert it("static") into json data type but wasn't able to fix this. anybody can help me to solve this question please.

Comment: I'm having a real hard time determining what you are trying to do based on your question.  What does the data look like? and what is your desired output?

Comment: What do you see in your console when you write `console.log(k);` (put it before the inner foreach

Comment: Please, fix the snippet. Add at least `$scope.arrCategory` data.

Comment: i just edited my question now, to understand you guys. i want to use a variable with a value "static" inside the foreach loop. but it is not working because it is in string format.how to convert the variable which having static value to json object and use it in the outer loop to run the inner loop further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i found the solution for the problem.

```
var variable = "keyname";
angular.forEach($scope.arrCategory[0][variable], function(k,d) {
    angular.forEach(k, function(kk, dd) {
        alert(dd);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your meaning, this returns the values of `name`, `picture`, and `price` in your (fairly convoluted -- you were missing the opening array bracket after `theme2`, but it was nigh impossible to notice that...) data structure. I just used plain vanilla JS, but the `angular.forEach` function will work similarly.

Edit: I think I finally understand the gist of your question, and it boils down to a basic JS concept: When you use dot notation in calling an object's properties, e.g. `object.foo`, JS looks for a property named `foo` on the object. When you use bracket notation, whatever is inside the brackets gets evaluated rather than read as a string. So, if you have `var foo = 'bar'`, and then you can call for `object[foo]` or `object['bar']`, and if the `bar` property exists on the object, that is what JS will return.

The below code works fine in angular, because it's fine to write vanilla JS in an angular application, or if you're sent on using an `angular.forEach()`, the following works, too:

```
    angular.forEach($scope.arrCategory[0][someKeyName], function(k,d){

        var thisKey = Object.keys(k)[0];
        var subKeys = Object.keys(k[thisKey][0]);

        angular.forEach(subKeys,function(key){
            console.log(k[thisKey][0][key]);
        });
    });
```

... as shown in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/catwceLe/);

Pre-edit answer below:

```js
var someKeyName = 'static';
var arrCategory = [{
    'static': [{
        'theme1': [{
            'name':'vari-1',
            'picture':'./images/static/theme-1/vari-1/1.jpg',
            'price':'10000'
        }]
    },
    {
        'theme2': [{
            'name':'vari-1',
            'picture':'./images/static/theme-2/vari-1/1.jpg',
            'price':'10000'
        }]
    }]
}];

arrCategory[0][someKeyName].forEach(function(k,d){
 //console.log(k);
    var thisKey = Object.keys(k)[0]; // ['theme1'], then ['theme2']
    var subKeys = Object.keys(k[thisKey][0]); // ["name", "picture", "price"]
 
    subKeys.forEach(function(key){
        console.log(k[thisKey][0][key]); // logged to console because the alert loop was annoying
    });
});
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: no this is not working for angular. i can not put   arrCategory[0]"static".forEach(function(k,d){}). but what i have to do is that.

Comment: it works either way, as you can use vanilla JS in angular: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/catwceLe/)